# Java blocking issue: Why would JVM block threads in many different classes/methods?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, locking, blocking, concurrent-programming

**Update:** This looks like a memory issue. A 3.8 Gb Hprof file indicated that the JVM was dumping-its-heap when this "blocking" occurred. Our operations team saw that the site wasn't responding, took a stack trace, then shut down the instance. I believe they shut down the site before the heap dump finished. The log had **no** errors/exceptions/evidence of problems--probably because the JVM was killed before it could generate an error message.

Original Question
We had a recent situation where the application appeared --to the end user--to hang.  We got a stack trace before the application restart and I found some surprising results: of 527 threads, 463 had thread state BLOCKED.

**In the Past**
In the past blocked thread usually had this issue:
1) some obvious bottleneck: e.g. some database record lock or file system lock problem which caused other threads to wait.
2) All blocked threads would block on the same class/method (e.g. the jdbc or file system clases)

**Unusual Data**
In this case, I see all sorts of classes/methods blocked, including jvm internal classes, jboss classes, log4j, etc, in addition to application classes (including jdbc and lucene calls)

**The question**
 what would cause a JVM to block log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger, java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance? Obviously some resource "is scarce" but which resource?

thanks

will

**Stack Trace Excerpts**

```
http-0.0.0.0-80-417" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000f6f1800 nid=0x1a00 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002dd5d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor68.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
                at org.jboss.ejb.Container.createBeanClassInstance(Container.java:630)

http-0.0.0.0-80-451" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000f184800 nid=0x14d4 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000003843d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
                at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)

"http-0.0.0.0-80-449" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000f17d000 nid=0x2240 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002fa5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.register(Http11Protocol.java:638)
                - waiting to lock <0x00000007067515e8> (a org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.createProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:630)


"http-0.0.0.0-80-439" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000f701800 nid=0x1ed8 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002f35b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
                at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger(Hierarchy.java:261)
                at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger(Hierarchy.java:242)
                at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:198)
```

Comment: How do the GC logs look?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are listed roughly in the order I would try them, depending on the evidence collected:

- Have you looked at **GC behavior**?  Are you under memory pressure?  That could result in `newInstance()` and a few others above being blocked.  Run your VM with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc` and log the output.  Are you seeing excessive GC times near the time of failure/lockup?

  - Is the condition **repeatable**?  If so, try with varying heap sizes in the JVM (-Xmx) and see if the behavior changes substantially.  If so, look for memory leaks or properly size the heap for your app.
  - If the previous is tough, and you're not getting an `OutOfMemoryError` when you should, you can tune the GC tunables... see [JDK6.0 XX options](http://www.md.pp.ru/~eu/jdk6options.html), or [JDK6.0 GC Tuning Whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).  Look specifically at `-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit` and `-XX:+GCTimeLimit` and related options. (note these are not well documented, but may be useful...)
- Might there be a **deadlock**?  With only stack trace excerpts, can't determine here.  Look for cycles amongst the monitor states that threads are blocked on (vs. what they hold).  I believe `jconsole` can do this for you ... ([yep, under the threads tab, "detect deadlocks"](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html#DeadlockDetection))
- Try doing several **repeated stacktraces** and look for what changes vs. what stays the same...
- Do the forensics... for each stack entry that says "BLOCKED", go look up the specific line of code and figure out whether there is a monitor there or not.  If there's an actual monitor acquisition, it should be fairly easy to identify the limiting resource.  However, some of your threads may show blocked without a transparently available monitor, these will be trickier...

Comment: It looks like we had an of OutOfMemoryException and that the jvm had started to dump-its-memory (i.e. HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError), but that operations had killed the jvm before it finished.  The log has no exceptions or OutOfMemory errors....

Comment: @user331465: Yeah, well, it may take some time before an OOM condition actually triggers OOM error.  See the XX options for the JVM on UseGCOverheadLimit, GCTimeLimit, GCHeapFreeLimit.  Probably this is part of your issue -- threads allocating memory were blocked not because of a lock per se, but because they were waiting to allocate memory.

Comment: @user331465: suggest you amend your question to include this information about GC/memory issues, as it focuses the question substantially.

Comment: how much GC time is excessive? In my application, jstat shows FGCT and CGT as ~90000. id that 90 sec?