# Thread dump blocked AND locked

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, synchronized, thread-dump

This is similar to [Java thread dump: BLOCKED thread without "waiting to lock ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067058/java-thread-dump-blocked-thread-without-waiting-to-lock).

Basically, I am seeing a BLOCKED thread but it has the lock it is waiting for:

```
"pool-1-thread-60" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbf10017000 nid=0x210 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fbed64e3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
        - locked <0x0000000742444ad0> (a org.apache.log4j.Logger)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
        ...
```

I would expect to see `- waiting to lock <0x0000000742444ad0>...` instead of `- locked...`.  The other question suggests that garbage collection is the cause but if that were the case wouldn't all threads be BLOCKED?  There are other threads which are RUNNABLE.  Also, how could I prove that was the case?  Why would this be the observed behavior?  I don't want to go blindly assuming it is the garbage collector only to find out days later it was something else.

**==Auxiliary info==**

Although I don't think it relevant to the issue at hand, this is the section of code that the above dump came from.

```
for(Category c = this; c != null; c=c.parent) {
  // Protected against simultaneous call to addAppender, removeAppender,...
  synchronized(c) { //line 204
if(c.aai != null) {
  writes += c.aai.appendLoopOnAppenders(event);
}
if(!c.additive) {
  break;
}
  }
}
```

Clearly there is a lock that needs to be obtained on that line.  HOWEVER, when a thread is truly blocked on this monitor the output in the thread dump appears like (this comes from the same dump):

```
"pool-1-thread-44" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbef0051000 nid=0x200 waiting for monitor\
 entry [0x00007fbed74f3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:204)
        - waiting to lock <0x0000000742444ad0> (a org.apache.log4j.Logger)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
        ...
```

The section of the dump I am interested in looks different ("locked" instead of "waiting to lock").  I have debugged many deadlocks and looked at lots of thread dumps.  What I always see is the "waiting to lock".  I have never seen a thread that is "locked" but still "waiting for monitor entry" and I want to know what that means.

Comment: Why do you think the thread has the lock for which it is waiting?

Comment: Because it says "locked".  When the thread doesn't have the lock it says "waiting to lock"

Comment: It holds a lock on 0x0000000742444ad0. But it's waiting for the lock 0x00007fbed64e3000.

Comment: 0x00007fbed64e3000 is the address range, not a lock.

Comment: The address range of what?

Comment: When the GC is stopping you application it also stops you taking a stack dump. If you have a stack dump, the GC hasn't stopped the application. I suggest you look at the source for that line of code to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known cosmetic bug in Oracle's HotSpot JVM. As you say, in your stack trace where you see `- locked <0x00007f3e9a0b3830>` it should actually say `- waiting to lock <0x00007f3e9a0b3830>` since the thread has not yet acquired the relevant lock.

See [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036823) for more details.

Comment: Is there any piece of code or function which helps me finding the thread/code line which currently locks this object? Have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

A lock is acquired on each `Logger` while iterating over its appenders to prevent concurrent changes to the appender collection. If one thread is blocked in an appender (for example, writing events over a network connection) other threads logging to that `Logger` instance must wait for the lock. An `AsyncAppender` can be used to buffer events and minimize contention, but at the risk of losing events in the buffer.

The strange thing is not that you see "locked" *instead of* "waiting to lock", but that you don't see "waiting to lock" *in addition* to "locked". That is, it appears that the thread in question is the one that won the race to acquire the log on a given category, and is now waiting to acquire an additional lock on some other object. The mystery, then, is why doesn't the dump identify the other object?

I think your assumption that its the `Logger` on which it already holds the lock is incorrect.

Still wondering what is the exact version you are using?

Comment: I certainly agree that there is a lock there.  However, in the thread dump, if a thread is waiting on a lock, it says "waiting to lock".  I'll post the relevant code as well as an example of what a normal blocked thread looks like.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I'm not sure you've identified the anomaly, but there is something weird here.